# Passing data from one activity to another using bundle - not displaying in second activity

Tags: android, json

I'm currently trying to take data acquired through a REST API call, parse it for the information I need, and then pass that information to a new activity.  I'm using the Asynchronous HTTP Client from loopj.com for the REST client, and then using the below code for my `onClick` and `onCreate` for the current and future activities, respectively.

Eclipse does not pass me any errors for any of my code, but when I try to run in the emulator, I get nothing (i.e. blank white screen) when the new activity/view opens.  I've tried to code with a different URL in my REST CLIENT, but I still see nothing.  I even took the API call out of the equation by commenting out the try/catch in `onClick` and changing `venueName` in the `bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", venueName);` to `searchTerm`.  Still, the new view comes up but nothing is displayed.  What is not being passed, or what am I forgetting to make the second activity show the `venueName`?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultsView.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String searchTerm = editText.getText().toString();


    //call the getFactualResults method
    try {
        getFactualResults(searchTerm);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Create the bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
    bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", venueName);  
    //Add the bundle to the intent
    i.putExtras(bundle);

    //Fire the second activity
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Method in second activity that should receive the intent and bundle and display it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the message from the intent
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Get the bundle
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    //Extract the data…
    String venName = bundle.getString(MainActivity.VENUE_NAME);        

    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(venName);

    //set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Two ways you can send the data. This is how you are sending it at the moment. And there is nothing wrong with it.

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", venueName);
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

In you code (second Activity) however, you are referring to the `key` in the Bundle as `MainActivity.VENUE_NAME` but nothing in the code suggests that you have a class that returns the value as the actual `key` name send with the Bundle. Change your code in the second Activity to this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String venName = bundle.getString("VENUE_NAME");        

//Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(venName);
```

You can check in your second Activity if the Bundle contains the key using this and you will know that the `key` is not present in the Bundle. The correction above, however, will get it working for you.

```
if (bundle.containsKey(MainActivity.VENUE_NAME))    {
    ....
}
```

Comment: This is a really great succinct yet fully detailed answer.  Thanks for writing that up so clearly.  It helped me understand how to use bundles very quickly.

Comment: Thanks. The example helped me.

Answer (score 5):

I think if you replace

```
String venName = bundle.getString(MainActivity.VENUE_NAME);
```

with

```
String venName = bundle.getString("VENUE_NAME");
```

it should work.

Here is how I handle my transfer of data from one activity to another:

Sending data to activity called "Projectviewoptions":

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
          b.putString("id", str_projectid);
          Projectviewoptions pv = new Projectviewoptions();
```

Receiving data:

```
idbundle = getArguments();
String myid = idbundle.getString("id");
```

The "key" on both sides should be same; in this case "id".

**Another way to send data, through intent is:**

Send:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ViewProjectDetails.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id", myid);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Recieve:

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are wrongly accessing the key which you have added in bundle. Besides getting the String as `MainActivity.VENUE_NAME` try to directly pass the key name which you have added in bundle as below:

Besides getting string as below :

> ```
>    //Get the bundle
>      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>     //Extract the data…
>    String venName = bundle.getString(MainActivity.VENUE_NAME);
> ```

Try to get the string using key name as below:

> ```
>     /Get the bundle
>      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>     //Extract the data…
>    String venName = bundle.getString("VENUE_NAME");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

to send bundle.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Name",Object); //This is for a String
i.setClass(CurrentClass.this, Class.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

to receive bundle

```
Bundle bundle = null;
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String myString = bundle.getString("Name");//this is for String
```

Comment: Here what is "i " . Please explain Meaning of I

Comment: If You Define Intent i = new Intent(); i am already try this Please explain Your answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the String you used as the key to put the item into your Bundle is the same as the key used to extract it. In your case, perhaps `MainActivity.VENUE_NAME` is not the same as "VENUE_NAME"

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 


bundle.putString("user_id", userId);

i.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(loginIntent);

LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.mytest;

import androidx.annotation.MainThread;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.mytest.MainActivity.STATIC_VARIABLE;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
   EditText editText1;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Bundle extras=null;
         extras=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null) {
          String recieved =extras.getString("TAG");
          editText1.setText(String.valueOf(recieved));
        }
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent backIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                String input= editText1.getText().toString();
                backIntent.putExtra("TAG2",input);
               STATIC_VARIABLE=3;
//    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
//                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                startActivity(backIntent);


            }
        });
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There no need to use `Bundle` just to pass a string (or any primitive data type).
You can use `i.putExtra("key", "value");` in the calling activity and
`String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");` in the called activity.