# Intent how to transfer 3 int values

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a little problem with my code. I want to transfer three int values in to my next activity. Unfortunatelly my following code returns me 3x one value. 
For example predkosc = 5 kat = 10 ramie = 15 and intent returns my in second activity predkosc = 15 kat = 15 ramie = 15
What is wrong iny my code?
Code A:

```
public  static String predkosc_VALUE = "";
public  static String kat_VALUE = "";
public  static String ramie_VALUE = "";
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Rzut_katapulta.class);
    EditText Text_predkosc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText Text_kat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText Text_ramie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String message_predkosc = Text_predkosc.getText().toString();
    int predkosc = Integer.parseInt(message_predkosc);
    String message_kat = Text_kat.getText().toString();
    int kat = Integer.parseInt(message_kat);
    String message_ramie = Text_ramie.getText().toString();
    int ramie = Integer.parseInt(message_ramie);

    intent.putExtra(predkosc_VALUE, predkosc);
    intent.putExtra(kat_VALUE, kat);
    intent.putExtra(ramie_VALUE, ramie);

    startActivity(intent);
```

Code B:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
predkosc = intent.getIntExtra(Main_menu.predkosc_VALUE,0);
katy = intent.getIntExtra(Main_menu.kat_VALUE,0);
ramie = intent.getIntExtra(Main_menu.ramie_VALUE,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public  static String predkosc_VALUE = "";
public  static String kat_VALUE = "";
public  static String ramie_VALUE = "";
```

Those keys are used to map the values in the intent, since all 3 are the same (empty) you are overwriting the value :)

change them to

```
public  static String predkosc_VALUE = "first";
public  static String kat_VALUE = "second";
public  static String ramie_VALUE = "third";
```

and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the *Bundle* to send data from one activity to another.
Pls Refer this: [Passing data from one activity to another using bundle - not displaying in second activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon)

Answer (score 0):

```
public  static String predkosc_VALUE = "";
public  static String kat_VALUE = "";
public  static String ramie_VALUE = "";
```

you have not initialised these variables!
 try:

```
 public  static String predkosc_VALUE = "myString1";
    public  static String kat_VALUE = "myString2";
    public  static String ramie_VALUE = "myString3";
```