# Get object from one Activity and display it on MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I have an app MainActivity > ContactActivity > SummaryActivity
On MainActivity I have a text view with directions for the user and once they enter their information I want to get the results from SummaryActivity and post it on MainActivty page. Once the user inputs the information I want the instructions to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

use bundle and pass as extra data with intent ...

see this thread
[Passing data from one activity to another using bundle - not displaying in second activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon)