# Error with the bundle on a new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I have a problem. I created a TCP client that executes in the new thread connection with Server. Unfortunately, the program shuts down. In LogCat I get the following message:

> "FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14635
>        Process: com.example.sebastian.ravia, PID: 8648
>        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras () on a
>   null object reference
>                at com.example.sebastian.ravia.ClientThread.run (TcpClient.java:36)
>                at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

The problem is in: "Bundle przekazanedane".
With this bundle I download the text to String of EditText from the previous Activity.

Here's the code:

```
public class TcpClient extends Activity  {
//private Socket socketIn;
//private Socket socketOut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client_activity);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
} }

class ClientThread extends TcpClient implements Runnable {

private boolean aRun = false;

private String aHost;
private String aSocketIn;
private String aSocketOut;

public void run() {

    Bundle przekazanedane = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(przekazanedane != null) {
        aHost = przekazanedane.getString("addressIp");
        aSocketIn = przekazanedane.getString("socketIn");
        aSocketOut = przekazanedane.getString("socketOut");
    }

    int aSocketInInt;
    int aSocketOutInt;

    aRun = true;

    aSocketInInt = Integer.parseInt(aSocketIn);
    aSocketOutInt = Integer.parseInt(aSocketOut);

    try {
        InetAddress serwerAddress = InetAddress.getByName(aHost);

        Socket socket = new Socket(serwerAddress, aSocketInInt);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
} }
```

Comment: are you passing bundle correctly through intent. visit to check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15445248/5202007

Comment: Get your `extras` in `onCreate()` before calling the thread

Comment: @codeMagic thank you for a solution. It works.