# Android error java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android

Full Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

              Process: com.intent.explicitintent, PID: 9871
              java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{c41d17d VFED..CL. ........ 80,80-400,148 #7f0d0075 app:id/numberOne}"
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                  at com.intent.explicitintent.MainActivity.add(MainActivity.java:40)
                  at com.intent.explicitintent.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I am trying to add simple addition.But it doesn't work.
I have two EditText fields and one Button. I want the result to be shown in another activity when button is click in TextView

Here is my code

Activity One.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText oneNumber;
EditText secondNumber;
Button button;

int e;
int b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    oneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOne);
    secondNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTwo);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add(v);
        }
    });


}


public void add(View view) {


    int a = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(oneNumber));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secondNumber));
    int result = a + b;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("add", result);
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);





}
```

}

Second Activity

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String result = extras.toString();
    total.setText(result);






  }

}
```

I think i mess up with getting the integer from EditText and getting the result inside textView in another activity

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is here:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(oneNumber));
int b = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secondNumber));
```

it should be:

```
 int a = Integer.parseInt(oneNumber.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.getText().toString());
```

`oneNumber`   is an `Editext` . You need to get the string from it

In your second activity get the result using:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total);
    //get result
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int result = intent.getIntExtra("add", 0);
    total.setText(String.valueOf(result));

  }
```

Comment: `String.valueOf` is redundant if you already have the string from `toString()`.

Comment: Still doesn't work.In second activity, how should i write to get the number?

Comment: For passing data using bundle see this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon)

Answer (score 1):

`String.valueOf(oneNumber)` is basically the same as `oneNumber.toString()`, which (as I'm sure you've figured out) is not the same as the text inside the box.

Perhaps what you mean is to use `oneNumber.getText().toString()` instead.