# How To Print a String in a TextView, when the value is taken from previous Activity

Tags: android

I m new programmer of Android Studio, I Just wanna know How to Print a string in a textview when the string is taken from previous activity by Bundle.
I Want to take value from one activity and show it to another activity through TextView. The Code I Use was:

```
public void imagebtn10(View view) {
    Intent StartNewActivity = new Intent(this, FinalPage.class);
    String code="Easy";
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


    bundle.putString("stuff", code);


    StartNewActivity.putExtras(bundle);


    startActivity(StartNewActivity);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

AND THIS IS MY FINAL ACTIVITY

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String stuff = bundle.getString(“stuff”);
```

But Now I Want to show the String "stuff" in Textview
So, Can Anyone tell How is it Possible??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data from one activity to another using bundle - not displaying in second activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon)

Answer (score 2):

```
    // in 1 activity ->
    String idValue = "hellow world";
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", idValue);
    startActivity(intent);
    //in second Activity->
    String i = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
```

Comment: But How To Show in a Text View?

Comment: textView.setText(i)

Answer (score 0):

If your TextView hasn't already got an id, for example "finalTextView", you can add that id in the layout by adding this line in the xml:

```
android:id="@+id/finalTextView"
```

So in your final activity, just add these lines:

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.finalTextView);
myTextView.setText(stuff);
```

That should be all.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a simple Example to get data from one activity and display into second activity. Hope this will help you

```
 --------------------activity1-----------------------------------
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String s=editText1.getText().toString();
                    String s1=editText2.getText().toString();



                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();

                    editor.putString("user",s);
                    editor.putString("id",s1);
                    editor.commit();
                    gotomainactivity();

                }
            });

            String userId=sp.getString("user",null);
            String password=sp.getString("id",null);
            if(userId!=null && password!=null){
                gotomainactivity();
            }

        }

        private void gotomainactivity() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Sharedatarecive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    ------------------------------------activity2--------------
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sharedatarecive);
            sep=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
            TextView textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);

            String s3=sep.getString("user",null);
            String s4=sep.getString("id",null);

            textView.setText(s3);
            textView1.setText(s4);
        }
```