# passing map coordinates to another activity in android studio

Tags: android, maps

I want to mark a location on a new map in a new activity. This is my code.

Ive sent my coordinates with putExtra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RealMap.class);

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putDouble("latitude",honey.latitude);
args.putDouble("longitude",honey.longitude);

intent.putExtra("bundle",args);
startActivity(intent);

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowHoney.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And I received them like this

```
double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");

if (bundle != null) {
    lat = bundle.getParcelable("latitude");
    lon = bundle.getParcelable("longitude");


    LatLng honey = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mylocation);
}
```

This isn't the full code I don't think there's a problem elsewhere. My code doesn't have problem compiling but when I try it on my phone it shuts down. It says the bundle is a null pointer. I don't know why it won't work.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

So I tried putting in if(bundle!=null) 
The app works, but it doesn't do what I really want it to, because the bundle is always null

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

Your PutExtra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RealMap.class);

intent.putExtra("latitude",honey.latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude",honey.longitude);

startActivity(intent);
```

Receive them like this

```
double lat=0;
double lon=0;

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if (bundle != null) {
    lat = bundle.getDouble("latitude");
    lon = bundle.getDouble("longitude");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, My bad. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("bundle")){

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
       if(bundle!=null){
         lat = bundle.getDouble("latitude");
         lon = bundle.getDouble("longitude");
    }
}
```

OR

Send it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowHoney.class);
        intent.putExtra("latitude", honey.latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", honey.longitude);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and recieve like this

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            Double lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0);
            Double lon = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
        }
```

Comment: I don't get it. I tried all of this but the bundle/ or the getIntent().getExtras() is always null!!!

Comment: Try second method I forgot to give the required parameters in new Intent()

Comment: Try without using bundle

Comment: I tried it without bundle but it's still null could what could i have done wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `Double` value and using `getParcelable()` at receiver activity. That is wrong. You should get `Double` value by using **`getDoubleExtra()`**.

```
    double lat = 0;
    double lon = 0;
    lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude",0); // default value 0, if 'latitude' is not passed.
    lon = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude",0);
    LatLng honey = new LatLng(lat, lon);
```

or by using `Bundle`

```
double lat=0;
double lon=0;

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");

if (bundle != null) {
    lat = bundle.getDouble("latitude",0);
    lon = bundle.getDouble("longitude",0);
}
```

**This will resolve your problem.**

**Suggestion:**

(1) Also Activity has default `putExtra()` method so you don't need to use `Bundle` object. Just use below code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RealMap.class);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", honey.latitude);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", honey.longitude);
    startActivity(intent);
```

(2) Create constant string keys for `putExtra()` and `getExtra()`.

Comment: why did you add  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowHoney.class); at the bottom??

Comment: It was copy mistake from your question, thanks, edited answer!

Comment: I did not use editor make this answer, So it was another typo mistake. Use getBundleExtra(), edited answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();

get bundle using this code and check if it is null or not.

Comment: It's still null

Comment: Have you check Location Object?

Comment: refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon]