# pass EditText to new Activity

Tags: java, android

I have in my `main_activity.xml` `EditText` and a `Button`.

Inside the `EditText` I insert a name and once I click the `Button` a new activity with new layout appears.

Now, I had like to use the value from the EditText inside my new activity (`hiscores.xml`) however the app crashes.

My MainActivity is as follows:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.opening_screen);

        button = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openHiScore();
            }
        });
    }

        public void openHiScore(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,HiScore.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

}
```

Then, inside HiScore the code is;

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class HiScore extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Name= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_text);
    String UserName = Name.getText().toString();

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hiscore);
    }
}
```

How do I correctly obtain the value inserted into the `EditText` to use it inside the string `UserName`?

Thank you!

Comment: Use bundle for passing the value from one activity to another, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon

Comment: Use a `Bundle` or `putXX()` of `Intent` to pass data, also whenever there's a exception related question, post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bundle to send data from one activity to another.Store data into the bundle  and create an Intent to put an extra Bundle in order to pass it.

```
public void openHiScore(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,HiScore.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("name", editText.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(b)
            startActivity(intent);

        }

In the HiScore class extract the data from the Bundle.

public class HiScore extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hiscore);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        // get the Bundle that stores the data of this Activity
        Bundle b = in.getExtras();

        // getting data from bundle
        String name = b.getString("name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from one activity to another, you will want to add the data as an **extra** to your `intent`.

```
    public void openHiScore(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HiScore.class);
        intent.putExtra("NAME_INPUT",nameString)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Then within the receiving activity, you want **retrive** the name from the `intent`:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hiscore);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME_INPUT");    
    }
```