# How do I send one value in a string Array from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android

I need to send that information to another activity. How will I be able to do that?

```
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
        contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        contacts.add(new Contact("Messy", "0516586348", "male"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Lisa", "0816957852", "female"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Grace", "0613253656", "female"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Ivan", "0826525298", "male"));
        contacts.add(new Contact("David", "0645956325", "male"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Bundle` like in some examples [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon)

best approach would be to make `Contact` `implements Parcelable`, then you may put into `Bundle` whole `ArrayList` (some short description of this mechanism in oficial [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles))